# How do I fix the Python "version error" on Command Prompt?

Tags: windows

[image: python error]

The image above shows that there is some error. I don't understand the error here as I already have Python installed. The same error occurs when I open a file using 'python filename.py'. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

you need to add Python in Environmental Variables in Windows ;)

Follow this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows)  or check the Python manual on the official page [here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#excursus-setting-environment-variables)

Here also a full screen to follow:
[image]

where the path should be your python's Script folder considering the path if you change or use a custom installation. If you install through the .exe tool it usually allows you configure this on install (or during install).

Comment: python.exe is located in the base installation directory, not the "Scripts" subdirectory -- except in a venv virtual environment. I know it's silly to require both directories in `PATH`. It's also silly that the directory is named "Scripts" instead of "bin". These quirks are legacies from the original port to Windows NT in the 1990s.

Comment: @eryksun you are more than right! :) I wanted a very fast screen shot just to illustrate the location and thus I simply took the one on my laptop